# MongoDB: snapshot read concern does not lock read documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

first of all, i have nothing to do with shards and clusters and replica set nodes , ...
my use case is a single instance of mongo db with 1 node replica set only to enable transaction

so i am starting a transaction with snapshot concern.
the Mongo freezes the world for me and gives me a snapshot of the world to work with.
then i find(read, query) some documents and based on their result, i update some other documents.
i have all rights to be assured to the documents that i first read, will be stay untouched, event if i have not touched them myself and i have only used them to judge about something.so although the mongo db will check the documents that are going to be updated right before update , to see if nobody else has touched them, i also need it to check whether those documents that i have only read and not updated, has stayed untouched.

but it does not.it only checks for the documents that are going to be updated.

so say i have designed my domain poorly and in order to let someone decrement something, i first check whether the guy has the right to do that. so i start a transaction and i check whether the guy has rights to do so and then i allow him to update another document and decrement something.but in between and before i commit my transaction, some other transaction, disqualifies the guy in the first uncommitted transaction to decrement and the first transaction happily goes ahead and commits his transaction without knowing that he has been disqualified to do so.

long story short: i want mongo to lock the documents i have read or check whether the documents i have read has stayed the same

Answer (score 0):

Snapshot read concern (and [MVCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) in general, which it is an implementation of) is a concurrency mechanism but not a locking mechanism. The behavior you are experiencing is expected.

If you want a lock, you need to implement the lock. You can do locking with unique indexes, conditional updates, probably with other mechanisms also.